# from pandas import * -- Python issue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to run the following code in python 3.3

```
    from pandas import *
```

and I receive the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\ProgrammingStuff\Python\FXCointegrationBacktesting.py", line 9, in <module>
    cannot import name text_type
    from pandas import *
    File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
    File "tslib.pyx", line 31, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:48782)
    File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types
    ImportError: cannot import name text_type
```

Not sure what the problem is, I am fairly new to python and I cannot currently find any solutions to this problem on stack overflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Judging from the error your installation is probably missing six package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/). Can you import it from interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) that depends on [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/).

In `dateutil <= 1.5` you don't need `six`, but those versions are not compatible with Python >= 3.0. So, the solution is to install `six`. However you do that is up to you.

You could do

```
pip install six
```

If you choose not to use `pip` it will depend on your system's package manager how you go about installing it.

Comment: I have six installed already. The six path is C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\six.

Comment: From the `pandas` directory do `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Then try again. What happens?

Comment: C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pandas>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: So you can successfully import `six` from the interpreter?

Comment: Yes I can import six with no problems.

Comment: How did you install `pandas`?

Comment: Installed from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas. The win32 python 3.3 version.